# Are some Flame Body/Magma Armor Pokémon better at hatching eggs?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a level 50 female Talonflame to make my eggs hatch faster, but I'd like it to be even faster.

I'm aware that Flame Body doesn't stack with Magma Armor.

I'm wondering if any Pokémon with Flame Body or Magma Armor hatches eggs the fastest, or maybe if gender and level matters.

Comment: If either answer has solved or at least clarified your issue can you please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 6):

The level or gender of the pokemon does not matter. Any pokemon with flame body or magma armor will halve the needed steps until the egg hatches.

Answer (score 2):

There is no sliding scale, either a party member has Flame Body or Magma armor and the time is halved, or you don't have Flame Body or Magma armor and it's the full time.

Flame Body and Magma armor DO NOT STACK, it is impossible to reduce it to less than half through this method alone.

However if you use the Hatching Power O-Power, this DOES STACK with Flame Body or Magma armor, allowing quicker hatching - and as you use it, it'll level up to be even faster.
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/O-Power

Answer (score -1):

they both work. I use my lv. 91 talon flame when hatching eggs and I ride on my bik up and down the day care road. it definitely makes it faster. even magma armor. it doesn't matter about level or gender.